# block in block cause self be retained, __block not work

Tags: objective-c, ios, block

Add: the problem happen when I copy the block inside the function:
   [block copy]

I am already using __block to avoid retain self.
                __block typeof(self) bself = self;

However, when there is another block in this block, and it use bself, self will still be retained.

As show in code below, the first bself will not retain self as expected. However, the 2nd bself will retain self.

```
            __block typeof(self) bself = self;

            [layer start:param1
                  completeHanlder:^{
                      bself.xx = localxx;

                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                          ... ...
                          [bself something];
                      });
                  }
             ];
```

anyone know reason behind ?

Comment: I do not know the reason behind it, but you can always use the same trick that you used to avoid self-referencing in the outer block by declaring a `bself2` inside the outer block, to be referenced inside the inner one.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've tried, still the same, self be retained...

Comment: Did you try changing `__block` for `__weak`? Since you are not planning to modify the variable, `__weak` may work better.

Comment: hmm, I just tried __weak, it would not prevent block. the retainCount now is 3. Each bself usage retain once.

Comment: Are you going off of retain counts, or actually observing a retain cycle preventing deallocation?

Comment: It needs to be weak under ARC, ARC will still retain block variables.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I observed a retain cycle preventing deallocation, then traced the retainCount, and found the issue.

Comment: @yorkdu great glad you found an answer! You should answer the question yourself and accept the answer so others can find it more easily :)

Answer (score -1):

You are doing wrong but concept it's right, here the error:

__block

This is used to let a strong reference inside your block. You could for example change value outside your block.

The right way is doing with __weak that will receive a weak reference from your instance and prevent strong loop reference like this:

```
 __weak typeof(self) bself = self;
```

And because __block that you created retain and strong reference :)